# My system is creating 1GB of syslog file Docker errors per minute

Tags: docker, log, logging, syslog, socks5

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Recently whenever I start my PC, I get a error message saying 0 bytes left in your /root directory. I used the `du` command and found out that `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/syslog.1` are tremendously big in size with syslog about 832M and syslog.1 about 44G. I deleted the syslog.1, but my syslog file is increasing at a rate of about 1G per minute.

syslog details:

```
samxaverian@sam-pc:~$ tail /var/log/syslog
Nov 20 09:50:36 sam-pc docker.dockerd[1845]: time="2019-11-20T09:50:36.040442741+05:30" level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission denied\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Nov 20 09:50:36 sam-pc docker.dockerd[1845]: time="2019-11-20T09:50:36.040490440+05:30" level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission denied\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Nov 20 09:50:36 sam-pc docker.dockerd[1845]: time="2019-11-20T09:50:36.040548312+05:30" level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission denied\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Nov 20 09:50:36 sam-pc docker.dockerd[1845]: time="2019-11-20T09:50:36.040601064+05:30" level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission denied\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Nov 20 09:50:36 sam-pc docker.dockerd[1845]: time="2019-11-20T09:50:36.040647849+05:30" level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission denied\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Nov 20 09:50:36 sam-pc docker.dockerd[1845]: time="2019-11-20T09:50:36.040700726+05:30" level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission denied\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Nov 20 09:50:36 sam-pc docker.dockerd[1845]: time="2019-11-20T09:50:36.040758378+05:30" level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission denied\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Nov 20 09:50:36 sam-pc docker.dockerd[1845]: time="2019-11-20T09:50:36.040806368+05:30" level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission denied\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Nov 20 09:50:36 sam-pc docker.dockerd[1845]: time="2019-11-20T09:50:36.040855320+05:30" level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission denied\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Nov 20 09:50:36 sam-pc docker.dockerd[1845]: time="2019-11-20T09:50:36.040909485+05:30" level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission denied\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
```

I noticed that this docker and socket connection error is getting repeatedly populated.

Comment: Step 1: Shut down your Docker container.

Comment: Step 2: Save one iteration of the docker syslog problem. Delete the rest to free up space on your drive.

Comment: Then you can actually start to work on the real problem.

Comment: I don't hav any running containers. Although still I used the docker system prune and docker system prune --volumes command, the problem still persists:

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188908/what-does-this-docker-log-entry-mean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this docker log entry mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188908/what-does-this-docker-log-entry-mean)